# What's the big O for determining users' "uniqueness" based on poll responses?

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I have a MySQL table of user responses to yes/no poll questions.  Looks kinda like this:

```
| user_id    | poll_id    | response
| 111        | 1         | 'yes'
| 111        | 2         | 'no'
| 111        | 3         | 'no'
| 222        | 1         | 'yes'
| 222        | 2         | 'yes'
| 222        | 3         | 'yes'
| 333        | 1         | 'no'
| 333        | 2         | 'no'
| 333        | 3         | 'no'
```

For a given user_id, I'd like to compute the similarity between their responses and every other user's responses.  So, user 111 and user 222 are 0.333 similar (because they have 1 out of 3 same responses), and user 111 and user 333 are 0.666 similar (because they have 2 out of 3 same responses).

I'd then like to determine the given user's median similarity value, and rank it against the median similarity value of all the other users to come up with a measure of that user's "uniqueness."

What would be the time complexity of this sort of operation?

*(Note: Currently, I have about 25,000 user_ids, 400 poll_ids, and about 500,000 rows in the response table.  Obviously, not all users respond to each poll question.  Would that affect the time complexity calculation?)*

Comment: With regard to your note, the number of records doesn't affect the expression of the time complexity, because the time complexity is expressed in terms of the number of records *as an independent variable.*  For example, quicksort is average-case O(n log n) and worst-case O(n^2) whether n is 50 items or 50 million items.

Comment: Hi phoog!  When I asked "Would that affect the time complexity calculation?" I wasn't referring to the number of records itself -- I was referring to the fact that not all users respond to each poll question.

Comment: I see.  In that case, how do omitted questions count towards the percentage?  If there are 3 questions and user A answers `Yes, No, Omit`, while B answers `Yes, Omit, No`, are they 50% similar because half of their submitted answers match, or are they 33% similar because their answers match for 1/3 of the total number of questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each user, you have to calculate the similarity with all other users; that's **n<sup>2</sup> - n**, or effectively **n<sup>2</sup>**.  But you also have to sort those results to find the median.  So, assuming your sort is **n log n**, the dominant term will be **n<sup>2</sup> log n**.

If you use the mean, rather than the median, you can get rid of the sort; then the time complexity would be **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

Comment: You can find the median in linear time: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Let's let `n` = the number of users, `p` = the number of poll questions, and `r` = total rows in the response table.  (In your case `n = 25,000`, `p = 400`, `r = 500,000`.)

For a single user the database will go through all of the responses, for each one doing a hash lookup to figure out whether it matches one of this user's responses.  If it does it takes `O(1)` time to keep track of a running tally.  It then takes that user's poll questions and does a straightforward sum.  As long as the number of responses is much bigger than the number of poll questions (it is in your case), this is dominated by the time to run through the responses.  So each user takes time `O(r)`.  You have `n` users, so the total time is `O(n*r)`.